# ORDER BY column containing a mix of text and numerical data

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, replace, sql-order-by

I want to sort a text column, where the numeric components should be sorted as numbers. The sorted result should look like this:

```
chr1
chr1,chr1
chr1,chr2
chr1,chr10
chr2
chr2,chr1
chr2,chr2
chr2,chr10
chr6
chr6,chr1
chr6_ux9
chr6_ux9,chr1
chr7
chr10
chr10,chr1
chr10,chr2
chr10,chr10
chr21
chr21,chr1
chr21,chr2
chr21,chr10
chrx
chrx,chr1
chrx,chr2
chrx,chr10
chry
chry,chr1
chry,chr2
chry,chr10
chrmt
chrmt,chr1
chrmt,chr2
chrmt,chr10
chr25
chr25,chr1
chr25,chr2
chr25,chr10
```

The following rules apply:

1. `chrx` is treated as `chr22`
2. `chry` is treated as `chr23`
3. `chrmt` is treated as `chr24`
4. `chr6_ux9` is a special case that should come after `chr6`

I tried different ways but not able to find the perfect solution. Please help me if anyone has an idea.

Comment: Should it be sorted per column or overall? Sort numbers like text? Please clarify what the result should look like and reduce the amount of data to what is needed for the problem.

Comment: overall table should be sorted based on this column.

Comment: i need to perform alpha numeric sorting

Comment: Looks like chromosomal data, right? I used my phantasy where your question remains unclear and added an accordingly `phantastic` solution.

Comment: I clarified your question. Please correct if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: This is a horrific way to store your data.  Redesign your database (or at least this column) into the separate pieces of information that you need.

Comment: @Erwin thanks for clarifying my question. Now it is giving the exact question.

Comment: @Erwin I tried your solution it is working fine.I am very thankful to you. And thanks to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Erwin, yes it is chromosomal data. you can see our website it is public portal.  http://explore.pediatriccancergenomeproject.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I understand now, what you are looking for. You want the **numeric components sorted as numbers**, not strings. This should work for you:

```
SELECT col1
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY string_to_array(
             replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
                col1
              , 'chrx',     'chr22')
              , 'chry',     'chr23')
              , 'chrmt',    'chr24')
              , 'chr6_ux9', 'chr6.6')
              , ' chr',     'chr')
              , 'chr',      '')
           , ',')::real[];
```

Sorts columns as depicted in the questin. The textual component ('chr') turns out to be redundant noise. After applying all replacements, I strip the noise and cast to a numeric array which can be used in the `ORDER BY` clause.

While performing the listed substitutions, the special case for `chr6_ux9` forces the use of `real[]` instead of the simpler and faster `int[]`, because the `integer` type leaves no room between `6` and `7`. You also have one column with a space instead of a comma. I added a substitution for that, too. But that's probably just a typo. After removing the irrelevant string `chr`, only comma-separated numbers remain, which can be cast to `real[]`.

BTW, [`replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is very fast. I have functions with dozens of `replace()` operations in a row that still perform fast. (`regexp_replace()` is much slower.)

---

#### Alternative answer for sorting individual elements

For a sorted output of **all** values as **strings**:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table(replace(replace(replace(
          col1
        ,'chrx', 'chr22')
        ,'chry', 'chr23')
        ,'chrmt', 'chr24')
        , ',') AS col1
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY 1
```

`chr6_ux9` comes after `chr6` automatically in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, for your quick response. I tried your code but not able to get alpha numeric sorting

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Your solution is working fine. In fact i struggled for last 3 days to find a solution.You gave me a excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect data model so to say... You should fix this by using a proper normalized model, but you could also use an [array datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html). An array can be sorted, indexed, etc.